# Text to Image function just outputs garbage

Tags: php

I'm attempting to convert text to an image with a custom font using the textttftext() function. I've scoured the internet for various solutions and nothing seems to work. I've ensured FreeType is enabled, I've attempted the putenv variant as mentioned in the docs, and I've tried different font files. No matter what I try, when I run the script it just outputs garbage to my console (like trying to cat a binary file). Other text-to-image functions work, just not textttftext(). Script is below, almost literally just ripped from the docs (also, I'm using Ubuntu in an EC2 but was having the same issues using WSL):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');


$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

$text = 'Testing...';


//imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
$font = 'arial';

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: You want to save the image into a file or output the image contents? This script will be run by a web server or by command line?

Comment: Just checking, but did you actually put the arial font file in the same directory as your PHP script?

Comment: I want to save it into a file and run via command line

Comment: yes, it is in the same directory

Comment: If I do that, it does not recognize the font. According to the docs, this issue is solved by what I have done above (putenv and removing the .ttf extension)

Comment: `imagepng()` is missing the file you want to put it in. Now the raw binary code is shown on the command line. And for the command line, the header is not needed.

Comment: That was it. Of course it was a stupid mistake like that. Thanks!